# Using the noexcept operator to chain noexcept declarations

Tags: c++, c++14

Why does the `noexcept` operator take an expression rather than a function signature/declaration?

Consider the following dummy example:

```
#include <string>

void strProcessor(const std::string& str) noexcept(true) { };

struct Type{
  void method1() noexcept(strProcessor("")) { //Error: Call to nonconstexpr function
     strProcessor("");
  }
};
```

It won't compile because `method1` has a non-constexpr expression in its noexcept, but why do I need to put an expression in there in the first place?

All I want to do is tell the compiler that **`method1` is noexcept iff an invocation of `strProcessor` with a succesfully constructed string is noexcept** (which it is).

So why not `noexcept(void strProcessor(const std::string&))`?

Another similar dummy example:

```
struct Type{
   Type(bool shouldThrow=false) noexcept(false) { if(shouldThrow) throw "error"; };
   void method1() noexcept(true) {};
   void method2() noexcept(noexcept(Type().method1())) { method1(); };
}
```

Here I'd like to say **`method2` is noexcept iff invoking `method1` on a succesfully constructed instance of Type is noexcept** (which it is in this case), but `Type` isn't even complete at the point where `method2` id defined.

Please explain if my understanding of this feature is wrong.

Comment: Well there's flexibility here as then you can do more clever things than simply naming a function. The expression won't be evaluated, so you can use `declval` and friends to avoid any side-effects and so forth. I don't really understand the error though as I'm not too hot on either `noexcept` or `constexpr`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
void method1() noexcept(noexcept(strProcessor(""))) {
//   Second 'noexcept'  ^^^^^^^^^                ^
```

The first one is the [`noexcept` *specifier*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec), which **specifies** whether or not `method1()` is *noexcept*.

The nested one is the [`noexcept` *operator*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept), which **checks** whether `strProcessor()` is *noexcept* when called with `""`.

Your second case is a bit tricky : `Type` is still incomplete at the point we'd like to use `method1()` inside `noexcept`. I've come to the following workaround, abusing a pointer-to-member :

```
void method2() noexcept(noexcept(
    (std::declval<Type>().*&Type::method1)()
)) {};
```

However, I don't think there's a case where you could only deduce `method2()`'s *noexcept* specification from that of `method1()`.

Comment: Thanks! Can you fix the second example as well?

Answer (score 2):

If you want some syntactic sugar when checking the `noexcept`ness of a function, you can use an auxiliary function like so:

```
template <typename R, typename... Params>
constexpr bool is_noexcept(R(*p)(Params...)) {
    return noexcept(p(std::declval<Params>()...));
}
```

And apply thusly:

```
void method1() noexcept(is_noexcept(strProcessor)) …
```

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a49a4740fa9b0659).