# C++ ISO noexcept of noexcept

Tags: c++, noexcept

In [the C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) there is the following definition:

```
template <class T, size_t N> void swap(T (&a)[N], T (&b)[N])
      noexcept(noexcept(swap(*a, *b)));
```

What does `noexcept(noexcept(swap(*a, *b)))` do?

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31654435/3233393).

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Having the `noexcept(x)` [specifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec) in a function declaration means that the function is non-throwing if and only if `x` evaluates to `true`.

`noexcept(y)` can also be used as an [operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept), evaluating to `true` if `y` is a non-throwing expression, and to `false` if `y` can potentially throw.

Combined, this means `void foo() noexcept(noexcept(y));` means: `foo` is non-throwing exactly when `y` is non-throwing.

In the case in the question, the function template `swap` for arrays is declared to be non-throwing if and only if swapping individual members of the arrays is non-throwing, which makes sense.

Comment: Good answer, probably one might want to read the [ref](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept) too.